# Clear Select2 before send ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

How can I clear the last results, before Select2 starts a new ajax-call? (Without changing the original select2-files)

To reproduce:

1. Select2 with ajax-function.
2. Search anything.
3. Search with other term.
4. The old results of step 2 are still visible unitl the ajax-query of step 3 is ready.

Comment: Do you really expect people to recreate those steps to help you? Would it not be more convenient for you to share/include the relevant source code with your question...

Comment: Its diffrent to make a working source for all, when I dont know a server (which responses the ajax-requests).

Comment: I didn't say "working" i said share the **relevant** source code. How else can anyone identify the existing problem you have? You can't assume everyone will write it the same way you have and without doing that will make it impossible to explain the reason for your problem or offer a solution without offering a complete rewrite.

Comment: It is a general question for select2. I can provide my code or I can provide the example-code of select2 for ajax-data-source, but I dont get the reason why I have to do that. I wrote the steps to clarify my situation.

Comment: So that means you expect others to dig around for the example source code to help you? well someone has given a solution so I won't waste time explaining why it would be better to provide the relevant source code with any question.

Comment: No, but I expect that sombody who needs to see a code for `select2-ajax-datasource` not able is to answer the question. In almost all cases is a source important, but not in all (like this question). I got only the downvote from you and a answer - maybe youre wrong?

Comment: You assume the downvote is from me. Be careful with such assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside ajax `data` handler you can clear items:

```
ajax: {
    type: "POST",
    url: '/echo/json/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function(params){
        console.log("ajax");
      // reset selection
      $('.select').val(null).trigger('change');
      var query = {
        search: params.term,
        items: data
      };
      return { json: JSON.stringify( query ) }
    },
    processResults: function (data, page) { 
        return { results: data.items };
    },
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/jb07ehpq/

Comment: Iam using loading-animations and error-messages. For a nice user-experience I changed the code `$('.select').val(null).trigger('change');`  to: `var results = $(this).data('select2').$results.children();

                if (results.length > 1)
                    results.last().remove(); `

Answer (score 0):

answer @akop is great, change quantity to zero:

```
 ajax: {
    url: url,
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
      var results = $(this).data('select2').$results.children();
      if (results.length > 0)
        results.last().remove();
      var query = {
        search: params.term
      };
      return query;
    }},
```